# Merge Problems SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, merge, unique-key

I'm trying to create a procedure that will take the values from a temporary table, and load them into another table. The second table has a composite unique constraint across its three columns (Not including the primary key) I'm using a merge statement to try and handle the upload, and keep getting an error saying

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 13
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_table'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.table'. The duplicate key value is (aaa, aaa, aaa).

I'm really confused because the whole reason I am using the merge statement is to prevent exactly this from happening. Here's the relevant portion of the procedure (With names changed, and the insertion to the temporary table changed)

```
create table #TempTable(Id int
                        , str1 varchar(3)
                        , str2 varchar(15)
                        , str3 varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #TempTable
           (str1 
           ,str2 
           ,str3)
     VALUES
           ('aaa','aaa','aaa'), ('bbb', 'bbb', 'bbb'), ('aaa','aaa','aaa')

MERGE dbo.table AS t
    USING #TempTable AS s
    ON (t.str1 = s.str1
    AND t.str2 = s.str2
    AND t.str3 = s.str3)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET t.str1 = s.str1
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (str1, str2, str3)
        VALUES (s.str1, s.str2, s.str3);

drop table #TempTable
```

I'm really confused as to why this isn't detecting duplicates, any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: After the USING statement your condition must not be - being met. So it is moving on to the INSERT - and then trying to insert a duplicate.

Comment: MERGE is not processed record-by-record, but as a set.  There is a snapshot taken of the target table at the beginning of the operation for comparison with the source records.  If you have duplicate keys in the source data (as here), they are both going to fall into the NOT MATCHED.  It's not like one of the rows causes an INSERT and then the second one CAUSES an update.  If you don't know your source data and could potentially have dupes, use a SELECT DISTINCT in the source data query.

Comment: The UPDATE does not make sense. It updates to the same value.

Comment: @Kevin Of Course! How stupid of me. Thanks, it worked perfectly, wish I could upvote more times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating the same row multiple times in the same statement. Understand that DML is set-based. The rows are not applied one after the other. This would force inefficient execution plans and is not in the spirit of SQL.

I'm not sure how duplicate updates is defined in SQL Server. I believe SQL Server defines that *at least one* of the duplicate updates happen. It is unclear which one comes through.

Here, we are dealing with inserts. You're inserting the same row twice. The writes are computed fully before any write is executed. That's why two inserts are being "queued".